# Visualforce as PDF with table format

Tags: apex, visualforce, pdf, repeat, table

I have a some content in my visualforce page which I am rendering as a PDF. I am unable to display the content of my VF in tabular format. below is the code which I am trying to get as a PDF file:

```
   <apex:repeat value="{!interviewSkillReviews}" var="interview">


        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!interview.Skill_review__r}" var="skillreview">

        <table border="1" cellpadding="6">
        <tr><td>    <apex:column value="{!skillreview.Skill__r.Name}"/> </td></tr>
        <tr><td>     <apex:column value="{!skillreview.Level__r.Name}"/>  </td></tr>
       <tr><td>      <apex:column value="{!skillreview.Skill_Level_Description__c}"/> </td></tr>
        </table>  
        </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:repeat>
```

But when I render this as PDF I do not see the content in table being displayed. It just appears as plain text. Please suggest a way to display those `<apex:columns>` in a table.

Comment: SfdcBat...is your issue resolved with duplicate post which your refereed ?

Comment: No , its not resolved yet. I am waiting for the resolution for that question so that I can click "That solved my problem" button.

Comment: looks like you voted to close this question as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things here - Try set a width on the table and avoid using visualforce styling elements as they're not fully supported by the PDF renderer. Try to stick as much as you can to plain HTML when generating a PDF. Maybe this will spit out a better result?

```
<apex:repeat value="{!interviewSkillReviews}" var="interview">
    <apex:variable var="skillreview" value="{!interview.Skill_review__r}" />

    <table border="1" cellpadding="6" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{!skillreview.Skill__r.Name}"/> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{!skillreview.Level__r.Name}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{!skillreview.Skill_Level_Description__c}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
</apex:repeat>
```